Blazorise Layout sidebar toggle not workin Blazor .net 8 in Interactive Auto
Moving my Blazor (using Blazorise) .net6 Web Assembly app over to .net 8 I am struggling to make the Blazorise Layout component make the  object to toggle (slide in and out).
This was working fine in my .net 6 app.
I suspect it is something to do with the fact that in InteractiveAuto, the Layouts (inheriting LayoutComponentBase) need to be server side rendered?
The typical  looks like this: (start tags)


<Layout>
    <LayoutHeader>
        <BarToggler Bar="@sidebar" />
        <div class="wlogohldr">
            <a href="" class="active b-bar-link">
                LOGO HERE
            </a>
        </div>
        <BarItem>
            <LoginDisplay />
        </BarItem>
    </LayoutHeader>
    <Layout Sider>
        <AuthorizeView>
            <Authorized>
                <LayoutSider>
                    <LayoutSiderContent>
                        <Bar @ref="@sidebar" Breakpoint="Breakpoint.Tablet" NavigationBreakpoint="Breakpoint.Tablet"
                             Background="Background.Secondary" ThemeContrast="ThemeContrast.Light" Mode="BarMode.VerticalInline"
                             CollapseMode="BarCollapseMode.Hide">
                            <BarMenu>
                                <BarStart>
                                -- Stuff in the bar --



I know this code works in .Net6 as a web assembly component.
If using the standard template stuff, that works because it is using Bootstrap which uses JS to do the work, I am not sure if Blazorise does the same (I am guessing not?)
I did see this question:Blazor 8: Server side rendering with interactive layout
But though it gives a lot of explanaitions, it is short on answers.
Any ideas?
